# Salesforce integration as a 3rd party application (Authentication and data sharing issue)

Tags: rest-api, integration, oauth2

I am in the process of integrating Salesforce and my application. I want to offer my users the capability of using some of their customer data in Salesforce in order to create a list of contacts in my application.

Currently, I have a quick prototype working using Salesforce's REST API with OAuth2. I have implemented 2 ways of accessing my customers data. The two of them have their advantages and disadvantages:

-- Username/Password: I got this OAuth flow working, and I can access all their data. I do not want to use this method though, because realistically no one would ever grant full access to their account.
[Reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/intro_understanding_username_password_oauth_flow.htm)

-- User-Agent: I got this working as well, and I have it so it redirects you to Salesforce (as a popup) so you can enter credentials, see what you are sharing with the app, and then authorize. I really like this one, but I was wondering if every single one of my customers is going to have to setup the so called "Connected App" in their accounts.
[Reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/intro_understanding_user_agent_oauth_flow.htm)

Ideally, the flow what I am looking for is to have the User-Agent flow, but without the headache of having to setup the ConnectedApp. I would rather define what objects is my app going to have permission to access (kind of like Facebook does) once, so that my users don't have to create a Connected App.

Please let me know if such flow exists, or if I would have to choose between those two.